# Middleman Add Pages for Secondary Language ONLY in a Multi-Lang Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, middleman

I'm using i81n for localization and the file structure is as shown below. I'm wondering if it's possible to add a single page for the secondary language only.

- locales (all the data for non-blog pages)

  - en.yml
  - es.yml
- source

  - localizable (all the pages that are shared in both languages)

I've tried adding a .html.erb file directly inside source folder which successfully added a page for English site only (en is the root site). But is there any ways I can add the page just for the Spanish site? Thanks!

---

Updates: Also tried adding a ES folder inside source and put the .html.erb file in their. This successfully created the page under /es but it's getting header and footer in English instead of Spanish.